How to Retrieve the Browser's Default Hover Color?
Is there a way to obtain the default hover color of a browser? For example, the select element has a default blue hover color in Chrome, but a gray hover color in Firefox. I am creating a custom select element that supports HTML, but the hover color is inconsistent with the other select elements on the page.
Firefox:

Chrome:


You could use javascript to create an element and simulate it's hover and the use getComputedStyle to check the background color.

I tried this alternative, but the script can't capture the hover color in chrome, only in Firefox. It seems to be an inheritance issue that Chrome handles differently from other browsers getComputedStyle('background-color') returns transparent, does not inherit ancestor's

One easy way is to add your custom color in the css of the component so that it will be consistent across browsers. For example consider the below code
Html
<select name="cars" style="width: 100px;color:grey" id="cars"onfocus='this.size=4;' onblur='this.size=0;'  onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>

css:
option:hover { background-color:grey; }


I'm working on a legacy project with multiple screens, so I can't generalize because it wouldn't make sense compared to other pages. A mass change might break an important style on some pages without me realizing it.

As I understood the requirement, @Luiz you want to pick up the browser's color so that your implementation can look like the built in select/option - is that right?
